# Matching for whole words in a string

Tags: java, regex

I have to verify an xpath if it contains whole words like 'and' or 'contains'.
'and' or 'contains' could be of any case(upper or lower case) and will not be suffixed or prefixed by any alphabet, could be prefixed or suffixed by any braces or parenthesis or space.

ex:

```
//view/section/headerRow[(col/label[contains(@value,'Role')]) and (col/label[contains(@value,'Demand')]) and (col/label[@value='Role Demand'])]


//view/pageToolbar[@secondaryTitle='[--Select--]' and @title='Plan:']
```

Can you please provide some quick solution using regex in Java?

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
boolean res = s.matches(".*\\bcontains\\b.*");
```

\b - word boundary

Comment: Will "[contains(" match?  I have to check for 'and' also at the same time.

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev
'\\' escapes the backslash; so '\\b' would escape the backslash and a b would be normal (i.e returning "\b")? Wouldn't you use '\b'?